# Call cdef function by name in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a bunch of `cdef` functions in Cython, that are called by a `def` function in a `pyx` file, e.g.:

```
cdef inline void myfunc_c(...):
    (...)
    return

def wrapper(...):
    myfunc_c(...)
    return
```

This works well. But to simplify not having to have a python wrapper for each `cdef` function, I was trying to index the `cdef` functions by name, either by assigning them to a dictionary or something like:

```
def wrapper(operation):
    if operation == 'my_func':
        func = myfunc_c
    func(...)
    return
```

But this doesn't work. Cython complains that it doesn't know the type of `myfunc_c`.

Is there any way to index or call the `cpdef` functions by name (e.g. use a string)? I also tried things like `locals()['myfunc_c']`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I haven't used Cython before but this doesn't seem to make sense - why would you be able to call myfunc_c *inside* a Python function, but not *outside* one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a *general* `cdef` functions this is impossible - they only define a C interface but not a Python interface so there's no introspection available.

For a `cdef` function [declared with `api`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#c-api-declarations) (e.g. `cdef api funcname()`) it is actually possible. There's an undocumented dictionary `__pyx_capi__`. This defines a dictionary (indexed by name) of PyCapsules containing function pointers. You'd then do

```
capsule_name = PyCapsule_GetName(obj)
func = PyCapsule_GetPointer(obj, capsule_name)
```

(where `PyCapsule_*` are functions cimported from the Python C API). `func` is a `void*` that you can cast into a function pointer of an appropriate type. Getting the type right is important, and up to you!

Although undocumented, the `__pyx_capi__` interface is relatively stable and used by Scipy for its `LowLevelCallable` feature, for example.

`cpdef` functions define both a Python and a C interface. Within a function they will be available in `globals()` rather than `locals()` (since `locals()` only gives the variables defined in that function.)

---

I don't actually think you want to do this though. I think you just want to use `cpdef` instead of `cdef` since this automatically generates a Python wrapper for the function.

Comment: Maybe I should indeed go the `cpdef` way. I was avoiding it for performance reasons: I do need to do some pure python operations inside the "wrapper" part and was concerned that with `cpdef` it would not be fully optimised.

Comment: It's probably worth timing it if you're worried. It's worth remembering that Cython does compile all of `def`, `cpdef` and `cdef` functions so the difference in speed is only from the function calling mechanism (and there won't be much difference between `cpdef` and `cdef`).

Comment: I've updated this with an alternative way that you can actually get `cdef` functions by name