# Is it possible to access a cdef'ed attribute of super class?

Tags: python, inheritance, cython

I have a simple base-derived inheritance tree, where I need to call one of the base's methods from an instance of the derived class:

```
cdef class base:
        cdef void nop(self):
                pass

cdef class derived(base):
        cpdef void nop(self):
                super(derived, self).nop()
                pass
```

If I import the compiled module and try to do

```
d = derived()
d.nop()
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'nop'
```

The error disappears if I `cpdef` the base's method, which makes me think that what I want to do is not possible without passing through python.
Is this the case? Is there a way to call the base's method from the derived class, if I need the base's method to be pure c?
(Please consider that I am fairly new to cython and I may be misunderstanding the difference between cdef and cpdef. The point is that I need this piece of code to be as fast as possible.)

Cython 0.29.14
Python 3.7.4

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174830/how-to-call-a-cdef-method

Comment: ...or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378704/call-cdef-function-by-name-in-cython

Comment: Thank you Joshua. Those questions do shed a bit more light on the details of calling cdef methods, but I guess my question was more related to the use of `super` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with `super` is that it's largely treated as a Python function return a generic Python object, which must be handled at runtime. `cdef` methods are only available when Cython knows the type at compile-time, and so it's unable to access them from the result of `super`. (Arguably a cleverer version of Cython probably should be able to figure it out in this case...)

Fortunately, there's another approach that's [illustrated in the Cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#c-methods): you just need to call the base class method explicitly (no introspection through `super`). In your case

```
base.nop(self)
```

The lack of `super`  shouldn't cause you problems since inheritance of `cdef class`es is pretty restricted (single inheritance from another `cdef class`), so you don't have to cope with the complicated situations that `super` is allegedly for.

Comment: I completely missed that bit of documentation. Thank you very much!

Comment: @sashashulgin It wasn't a hugely obvious bit of documentation to be fair